# Creating transparent Docker network breaks AWS CLI

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, docker-for-windows

I'm running Docker version 17.06.2-ee-6, build e75fdb8 on Amazon EC2, Windows Server 2016. The instance role has permissions to get files from one specific S3 bucket:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket/*"
    ]
}
```

In general, if I run `aws s3 cp s3://my-s3-bucket/my-file .`, it downloads successfully. However, if I create a transparent Docker network using the following command:

`docker network create -d transparent networkName`

and then run the same AWS CLI command, it returns

`fatal error: Unable to locate credentials`

If I then remove that network

`docker network rm [thatNetwork]`

the download works again.

Why is creating a transparent network having this effect?

Edit: it looks like it's access to the AWS metadata IP address (169.254.169.254) that's being blocked. Still don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue, and worked around it by adding a second NIC and changing the routes to direct 169.254.169.254 to the new NIC.

1. `route print` will show the NIC indexes at the top under the `Interface List` section
2. `route -p delete 169.254.169.254` removed the old route
3. `route -p add 169.254.169.254 mask 255.255.255.255 <gateway> IF <interface id from step 1>` will direct traffic to the metadata api via the second nic